# using a dropdown and Javascript switch function to control display of page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to include a dropdown on a page to control the display of prices in different currencies. I don't need to do currency conversion on the fly.

I was hoping to set up some spans, each containing value for a particular currency, and have dropdown on the page. When a user selects a currency, the javascript makes sure the correct span is showing, and hides all the others.

so far I have got the following but can't get it to work :( any hints on where I am going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#CAD {
display:show;
}

#USD, #EUR, #GBP, #ANG {
display:none
} 
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<select id="currency">
<option value="0">CAD</option>
<option value="1">USD</option>
<option value="2">EUR</option>
<option value="3">GBP</option>
<option value="4">ANG</option>

</select>


<span id="CAD">CAD $100</span>
<span id="USD">USD $200/span>
<span id="EUR">EUR €300</span>
<span id="GBP">GBP £400</span>
<span id="ANG">ANG ƒ500</span>
<script>
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
switch (this.value) {
case 0:
    $("#CAD").show();
    $("#USD").hide();
    $("#EUR").hide();
    $("#GBP").hide();
    $("#ANG").hide();
    break;
case 1:
    $("#CAD").hide();
    $("#USD").show();
    $("#EUR").hide();
    $("#GBP").hide();
    $("#ANG").hide();
    break;
case 2:
    $("#CAD").hide();
    $("#USD").hide();
    $("#EUR").show();
    $("#GBP").hide();
    $("#ANG").hide();
    break;
case 3:
    $("#CAD").hide();
    $("#USD").hide();
    $("#EUR").hide();
    $("#GBP").show();
    $("#ANG").hide();
    break;
case 4:
    $("#CAD").hide();
    $("#USD").hide();
    $("#EUR").hide();
    $("#GBP").hide();
    $("#ANG").show();

}


});
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
        $('.currency').hide();
        $('#currency').on('change', function () {
            $('.currency').removeClass('active');
            $('.currency').hide();

            $('#'+$(this).val()).addClass('active');

            $('span.active').fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

HTML code;

```
<select id="currency">
    <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
    <option value="ANG">ANG</option>

</select>

<span id="CAD" class="currency">CAD $100</span>
<span id="USD" class="currency">USD $200</span>
<span id="EUR" class="currency">EUR €300</span>
<span id="GBP" class="currency">GBP £400</span>
<span id="ANG" class="currency">ANG ƒ500</span>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! although I commented out ' $('.currency').hide();' on first line to make a default value show on page initiation

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues  in you code :

1.span tag not closed :

```
<span id="USD">USD $200/span> // worng
<span id="USD">USD $200</span> // Correct
```

2. Wrong id of dropdown used :

   ```
   <select id="currency"> // id of dropdown
   $('#purpose').on('change', function ()
   {
   }); // wrong id used


   $('#currency').on('change', function ()
   {
   }) // correct id
   ```

3 .

```
    switch (this.value) // wrong
    switch ($(this).value) // correct
```

4. Use break here :

   case 4:
   $("#CAD").hide();
   $("#USD").hide();
   $("#EUR").hide();
   $("#GBP").hide();
   $("#ANG").show();
   break;

Comment: Thansk so much for taking the time to review my code and point out these errors. I made amendments as suggested but still couldn't get it to work so ended up using syntaxe's answer. - But i really am grateful for the time you spent.